# Instead of a file path to open the program, search and open the file in the same directory as the program

Tags: c#

This code wants me to give a file path but i need it to open testfile.txt in the same directory as the program, not by a given path. Could anyone help me?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Test\\testfile.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a relative path like this:

```
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("testfile.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

In this case the `testfile.txt` is specified a relative path to the location of the executable.

You will also uyndoubtfully notice how I wrapped the IDisposable `StreamReader` in a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal and freeing the associated handle even in the case of an error.

Comment: This opens the file in the current directory, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will look for the file in the same directory as the executable which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I doubt it will...if I have a shortcut with a working folder set in \temp I believe your code will open the file from the \temp folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You helped me figure how to do it, i've posted it    as an answer, so if anyone hasn't figured it out yet then can look at yours or mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be absolutely sure that your file is read from the same folder where your app is located read its commandline.

Using Darin's example:

```
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                  Path.Combine(
                      Path.GetDirectoryName(
                             Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]),
                     "testfile.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

If you only open the file without any path the CurrentDirectory is used, which can be different as shown by the output of this code:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]).Dump();
Environment.CurrentDirectory.Dump();
```

shows:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4
>   e:\prj

because I started LinqPad from a commandprompt in `e:\prj`. Opening or writing a file without a path in this case uses the directory e:\prj to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate. I can't believe i didn't think about this myself. The code itself was working with a path. To make it open a file in the same directory as the program just change the whole ("c:\path\path"); to ("filename.txt");

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("testfile.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

P.S - This code is a button that when clicked opens a file named testfile.txt in listBox1.